# json converter error = moshi Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

How to config **Moshi** so that below `field2` from JSON
will be converted to String `"{"subfield21":"asdf","subfield22":"1234"}"`
in code `MyData.field2`

JSON:

```
{
   "field1":"someValue1",
   "field2":{
      "subfield21":"asdf",
      "subfield22":"1234",
   }
}
```

Kotlin class:

```
data class MyData(
  val field1: String, val field2: String
)
```

Whan I try std Moshi config I get an exception:

```
moshi Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path
```

Note: I'm using standalone Moshi, without retrofit.

Comment: by the way, if you just need to do this because of the extra comma after subfield22, you can make a "lenient" adapter with Moshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is JsonReader.nextSource(). Here's an adapter factory to do the job.

```kotlin
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class JsonString {
  object Factory {
    @JsonString @FromJson fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): String {
      return reader.nextSource().use(BufferedSource::readUtf8)
    }

    @ToJson fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, @JsonString value: String) {
      writer.valueSink().use { sink ->
        sink.writeUtf8(value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how you can use it, using the JsonQualifier annotation we made above.

```kotlin
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class MyData(
  val field1: String, @JsonString val field2: String
)

fun main() {
  val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(JsonString.Factory)
    .build()
  val adapter = moshi.adapter(MyData::class.java)
  val decoded = adapter.fromJson(json)!!
  decoded.field2 == """{"subfield21":"asdf","subfield22":"1234",}"""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't fit object inside string.

Try

```
data class MyData(
  val field1: String, val field2: SubMyData
)
data class SubMyData(
  val subfield21: String, val subfield22: String
)
```

Comment: but in `field2` client can insert any data
so I want to decode it as `String` 
BTW. works `data class MyData( ...  val field2: Any)` but I prefer `String` ;]